# Maximum height for table header, expand horizontally if not enough

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table with arbitrary number of columns, and arbitrary headers.

I'd like to set the maximum height for the header.
And if the height is not enough to fit the text, I'd like cells to stretch horizontally, with possible horizontal scroll for the whole table.

CSS and/or javascript (JQuery) solution needed.

On the figure below, I'm happy with **1.** and **2.**, not happy with **3.** or **4.**, and would be happy with **5.**, if underscores were spaces and wasn't placed there manually.

[image]

```css
.overflow-x {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 20px;
}

td>div {
  max-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:300px; background-color:#fde; padding:10px">

  <ol>
    <li>

      <div class="overflow-x">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>quick</td>
            <td>brown</td>
            <td>fox</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

    </li>
    <li>

      <div class="overflow-x">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>the quick brown fox</td>
            <td>jumps over</td>
            <td>the lazy dog</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

    </li>
    <li>

      <div class="overflow-x">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</td>
            <td>the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</td>
            <td>the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

    </li>
    <li>

      <div class="overflow-x">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

    </li>
    <li>

      <div class="overflow-x">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>the_quick_brown_fox jumps_over_the_lazy_dog</td>
            <td>the_quick_brown_fox jumps_over_the_lazy_dog</td>
            <td>the_quick_brown_fox jumps_over_the_lazy_dog</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

    </li>
  </ol>

</div>
```

Comment: Ooof.  Not an easy set of requirements.

Comment: make this a single table or make it a list displayed as table-row !! what is it ? a table or a simple list ?

Comment: @G-Cyr the list is the list of samples. Each sample has a table in it, of the kind the the question is about.

Comment: okay, i guess i misunderstood the question. is that what you try to do ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QqeQMX unfortunately, this is a trick where the div max-height will not make the table expand horizontaly :(

Comment: @G-Cyr It's not exactly - I'd like the scroll to appear after 2 lines (in this case) fill up. In your example the second row starts to scroll before filling up 2 lines, and if I replace -150% with -1500% which might be necessary, the same happens with the other lines as well. If I needed one line only, this would be the solution.

Comment: flex could help a litlle more ....  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/boXLOX

Answer (score 0):

Try this. JS could be simplified if there's just one table on the page, but I ran it through an `.each` to make sure each table was managed independently. This sort of incremental thing is obviously not the best performance-wise, but maybe your approach can handle that.

One gotcha is that I think the line height of the text MUST be defined in this approach. You've got it in your CSS already, but this makes it non-optional, or else you need to define the pixel value of the max height in some other way, as this approach isn't trying to parse how many lines the text is breaking onto, it's just looking at how tall the first tr row is (another simplification could be if you used a `<thead>` or `<th>`.

```js
$('.overflow-x').each(function() {
  var maxHeight = 2*parseInt($(this).find('tr:first td').css('line-height'));
  var initWidth = $(this).width();
  for (i = initWidth; i < 1000; i++) {
    var height = $(this).find('tr:first td').height();
    if (height <= maxHeight) { break; }
    $(this).find('table').width(i + 1);
  }
})
```

```css
.overflow-x {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:300px; background-color:#fde; padding:10px">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <div class="overflow-x">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>quick</td>
            <td>brown</td>
            <td>fox</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="overflow-x">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>the quick brown fox</td>
            <td>jumps over</td>
            <td>the lazy dog</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="overflow-x">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</td>
            <td>the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</td>
            <td>the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="overflow-x">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="overflow-x">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>the_quick_brown_fox jumps_over_the_lazy_dog</td>
            <td>the_quick_brown_fox jumps_over_the_lazy_dog</td>
            <td>the_quick_brown_fox jumps_over_the_lazy_dog</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: So, you increase the width of the table till it fits the required height, right? This seems to be too brute-force to me. I hope for a more elegant solution. Good thing to know this works though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. It's not very flexible, since it allows only text in table cells. But it doesn't depend on browsers table formatting.

```js
var maxHeight = 70;

var $scratchpad = $("#scratchpad");
var space = $scratchpad.find("span").width();

fit();

function fit() {
 if($('.overflow-x table').height() <= maxHeight)
   return;

  $('.overflow-x table tr:first td div').each(function() {
    var $div = $(this);
    $scratchpad.html(
      $div.text().trim().replace(/\s+/g, " ").split(" ")
        .map(function(word) { return "<span>"+word+"</span>"})
        .join("")
    );
    var widths = $.map($scratchpad.find("span"), function(span) { return $(span).width(); });

    $div.width(findLeastWidth(widths, 2)+1);

    function findLeastWidth(widths, lines) {
      var totalWidth = widths.reduce(function(sum, w) {return sum+w}, 0)
        + space * Math.max(0,(widths.length - lines));
      if(lines == 1 || totalWidth == 0)
        return totalWidth;
      var minWidth = totalWidth / lines;
      for(var w1 = widths[0], i1 = 1; w1 < minWidth && i1 < widths.length; i1 ++)
        w1 += widths[i1] + space;
      return Math.min(
        Math.max(w1, findLeastWidth(widths.slice(i1), lines-1)),
        Math.max(w1 - widths[i1-1] - space, findLeastWidth(widths.slice(i1-1), lines-1))
      );
    }
  })
}

setTimeout(function() { setInterval(function() {
 generate();
  fit();
}, 500); }, 2000);


function generate() {
 var lorem = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.".split(" ");
  var html = "";
  for(var i = 0, nCols = Math.random()*8+1; i < nCols; i++) {
   html += "<td><div>";
   for(var j = 0, nWords = Math.random()*Math.random()*8+1; j < nWords; j++)
     html += lorem[Math.floor(Math.random()*lorem.length)]+" ";
   html += "</div></td>";
  }
  $('.overflow-x table tr:first').html(html);
}
```

```css
.overflow-x {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid navy;
}
#scratchpad {
  white-space: nowrap;
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:350px; background-color:#dfe; padding:10px">

<div class="overflow-x">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><div>quick</div></td>
      <td><div>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div></td>
      <td><div>over the lazy dog</div></td>
      <td><div>fox jumps over the lazy dog</div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

</div>

<div id="scratchpad">
  [<span> </span>]
</div>
```

Still, I'd like to see a better solution.